# Anyone got autofs work with Elementary OS?

Tags: mount, sharing

I'm trying to get autofs work with nfs shares with no luck.

I can mount them myself, but autofs do not work.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs

Used settings from that help.

Answer (score 0):

I have autofs mounting nfs shares using `/net` but not tried any other rules. So my `auto.master` looks like this:

```
# auto.master
/net    -hosts
+auto.master
```

I think `autofs.conf` and `auto.net` are default. Check `auto.net` is executable (`chmod 755`) as per the comment in that file. Restart the service, then

```
$ ls /net/<hostname>/
```

should list the exported areas for the host.

I'm pretty sure `/net` gets created when autofs starts, if not you can create it yourself with

```
$ sudo mkdir /net
$ sudo chmod 755  /net
```

and restart the service again.

Comment: Do you use NFS or NFSv4? I use NFSv4 and I don't understand why it won't work..

Comment: Oh, I am using regular NFS defaults. Not tried v4. What do you have in your exports file on the server?

Comment: I use freebsd as my nfs server.

% cat /etc/exports <br>
V4: /shared  <br>
/shared

Comment: Sorry, not sure what the answer is but if you are using the auto.nfs script then you can check if it sets the right options. I doubt it does though.