# NFS Shares from my NAS doesn't appear at startup

Tags: networking

I have tried all the examples on this forum but still no avail.

I have nfs-common install and edited my /etc/fstab file with these lines to mount my two shares.

192.168.1.5:/data/Music /mnt/LIBATNETNAS/Music nfs user,noauto,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr
192.168.1.5:/data/Videos /mnt/LIBATNETNAS/Videos nfs user,noauto,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr
192.168.1.5:/data/Documents /mnt/LIBATNETNAS/Documents nfs user,noauto,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr

It just doesn't mount at startup, while mounting them individually works.

I can even use this command manually and it works.

sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.5:/data/Music /mnt/LIBATNETNAS/Music && sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.5:/data/Videos /mnt/LIBATNETNAS/Videos && sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.5:/data/Documents /mnt/LIBATNETNAS/Documents

It just doesn't work at startup on Elementary OS, all other distros work which is a bit frustrating.

I hope anyone can help.

Thanks!!!

Comment: look for automount nfs https://www.linuxtechi.com/automount-nfs-share-in-linux-using-autofs/. https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/14129/anyone-got-autofs-work-with-elementary-os

Comment: This actually works but only on one share, it doesnt mount my two other shares.

heres my auto.nfsdb file

Music   -fstype=nfs,rw,soft,intr   192.168.1.5:/data/Music
Videos   -fstype=nfs,rw,soft,intr   192.168.1.5:/data/Videos
Documents   -fstype=nfs,rw,soft,intr   192.168.1.5:/data/Documents

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. Delete those three entries from nfsdb file and add instead of them these three:

```
Music       -fstype=nfs4,rw,soft,intr   192.168.1.5:/data/Music 
Videos      -fstype=nfs4,rw,soft,intr   192.168.1.5:/data/Videos 
Documents   -fstype=nfs4,rw,soft,intr   192.168.1.5:/data/Documents
```

One below other, probably the first one is working and other two not, because they are not below. If nfs4 will not work, change it to nfs.

Comment: Thank you!!! It sort of works, it works when I go to the folders using the command line the first time. It doesnt auto load. I have to go to the Music, Videos and Documents folder to sort of enable it. i just got used to the fstab way that it just works without doing anything